# Sending Complex Arrays from Client side(Javascript) to Server Side (ASP.NET MVC2)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, arrays

I have this controller:

```
public HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult(MyObj[] myObjArr)
   {
   }
}
public class MyObj
{
  public Datetime d {get;set;}
  public int x{get;set;}
  public string yy {get;set;}
}
```

My javascript code is the following:

```
var obj = { d:new Date(), x : 10, yy : 'hello' };

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: server,
            dataType:"json",
            data: {obj,obj},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

It simply dont work, i've tried:

```
$.JSON({obj,obj});
JSON.stringify({obj,obj});
```

On data but nothing.
Every possible combination i've probably tried out but on server side myObjArr just keeps at null, i've tried numerous walkthroghts, i replaced [] to List, ICollection, etc
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: > `data: {obj,obj}`  That's not valid JavaScript. Surely you see the `SyntaxError` in your console.

Comment: arr = []; arr.push(obj);arr.push(obj); you surely get the idea . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems fine for me.

```
public HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult(MyObj[] myObjArr)
   {
   }
}
public class MyObj
{
  public Datetime d {get;set;}
  public int x{get;set;}
  public string yy {get;set;}
}
```

JS:

```
function makeParams(arr, namespace) {
    var tempObj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var o = arr[i];
        for (var k in o) {
                tempObj[namespace + "[" + i + "]." + k] = o[k];
        }
    }
    return tempObj;
}

var arr = [{ d:new Date(), x : 10, yy : 'hello' }];
var namespace = "myObjArr";
var data = makeParams(arr, namespace); //eg. { 'myObjArr[0].x': 10 }
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: server,
            dataType:"json",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```